# A statistic that describes variation in a stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, signal-processing

Lets suppose we have two realizations from two stochastic processes.
[image: Variation]

If we look at the values at y-axis as samples, both of these realizations have the same variance, but the second one is clearly more variant than the first (if we consider time as a factor). Is there a statistic that can describe this kind of variation? I'm looking for a statistic that is lower in the first picture and higher in the second.

P.S. Sorry if I didn't use the proper words; I'm not very familiar with the stochastic processes' literature.

Comment: This question is more fitting for the stats SE. In any case, it may be that what you're looking for is studying the process $\Delta X_n=X_n-X_{n-1}$. This is called (first) differencing and it is very standard.

Answer (score 2):

The [total variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation) may be what you are looking for. For functions in $\mathcal{C}^1$, the total variation over an interval $[a,b]$ is given by

$$
V^b_a (f) = \int_a^b { \left| f'(t) \right| \mathrm{d}t}.
$$

For a discrete signal $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^N$, the total variation is often defined as

$$
\mathrm{TV}(\mathbf{x}) = \lVert \mathbf{Dx} \rVert_1,
$$

where $\mathbf{D}$ is the first-order difference operator. Total variation minimization has some interesting applications, such as [image denoising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_denoising).